# Version range in debian/control

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

When declaring dependencies in `debian/control` to create a package, I can specify a lower or upper bound on the version. For example, if I depend on `libvtk6-dev` being at least version `6.0.0` I can write in the `Depends` line:

```
 libvtk6-dev (>= 6.0.0)
```

But is it possible to specify a range? For example, if I depend on the version 6.0 or 6.1 of a package, but not 6.2 or 5.9, how would I specify that?

A more complex example would be if dependencies of a package changes depending on the version. For example, `libvtk6-dev` has missing dependencies, but this changes depending on the version of the package installed. How can I say something like: if `libvtk6-dev` is version 6.0 or 6.1 then also depends on `libpython2.7-dev`, and if the version is greater or equal to 6.2 then depend on `libproj-dev`?

Answer (score 3):

- So let's break it down:

  ```
  libvtk6-dev (>= 6.0.0), libvtk6-dev (<< 6.2.0), libpython2.7-dev
  ```

  OR (logic op)

  ```
  libvtk6-dev (>= 6.2.0), libproj-dev
  ```

  `,` in `Depends:` is like AND (logic op). `|` is OR (logic op) but they don't have same priority neither brackets to be combined directly in that order/form.
- Here what I could come with:

  ```
  libvtk6-dev (>= 6.0.0), libvtk6-dev (>= 6.2.0) | libpython2.7-dev, libvtk6-dev (<< 6.2.0) | libproj-dev
  ```

  How to read it:

  1. Must `libvtk6-dev (>= 6.0.0)`
  2. If NOT `libvtk6-dev (>= 6.2.0)` then `libpython2.7-dev`
  3. If NOT `libvtk6-dev (<< 6.2.0)` then `libproj-dev`

Funny thing, this way is similar to [NOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_logic) (or [NAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic)) logic in electronics. If you have one of these then you can create all logic operations from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `<<` example:

```
 libvtk6-dev (>= 6.0.0),  libvtk6-dev (<< 6.2.0)
```

This way you have locked the range between 6.0.0 and 6.1.0. The same way you have to specify for each package individually, there is no if this dependency is this then ask for that.

Comment: And can we combine that with the more complex example?